# is there any way to change price of in app purchase dynamically .?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

My application had in-app-purchase functionality and  there is requirement to change the price of in app purchase dynamically.

so there is any way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"? Also, although I suspect the answer is "no" in all cases, it would really help to know what market you are talking about. Google Play/Android Market? Amazon AppStore? Something else?

Comment: Change price dynamically based on the entropy of the system?

Comment: @TedHopp I am talking about google play store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to change the price of in app purchase dynamically.
But maybe you can do one other. you can have a number of products of different prices and choose which product to but dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there isn't an easy way to implement this. IOS is in the same boat. You have to have the inapp item defined before you can use it. One way around this is to create multiple levels of pricing.

- Item_10 - 10$
- Item_20 - 20$
- Item_30 - 30$

Then when you go to purchase the product, you can dynamically change the product code to whatever price you want. This is the closest thing I have found so far that works with their framework. One other option is to have a single item.

- Item_1 - 1$

Then you sell it by quantity. (x10 of Item_1 is 10$). I have not tried this method yet and unsure if google/ios offers quantity at the moment but its something to look into.

Comment: but its  just a hack, not a proper way to do that,
because what will you do  when you have a long list of product with different price...???

Comment: @ImranSamed Agreed, definitely is not the proper way to do it. This was more a way to get around the missing features. I would hope they have gotten closer to implementing this by now but not sure.